# Are higher versions of the .NET Framework compatible with lower versions?

Tags: .net

If an application requires .NET Framework 1.1, will it work if I have .Net Framework 3.5 or 4 installed?

When trying to start a application, I was getting the error

> "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application".

I read on another site that installing .Net Framework 1.1 will solve it. I downloaded and installed v4. NOw the error is gone, but now it shows

> "the requested operation failed".

Comment: Update: I just downloaded and installed .Net 4. It did not work :(

Comment: "Did not work" tells us essentially nothing. If someone else arrives later with the same question, it would be useful to know what exactly didn't work.

Comment: When trying to start a application, I was getting the error "application failed to initialize properly 0xc0000135". I read on another site that installing .Net Framework 1.1 will solve it. I downloaded and installed v4. NOw the error is gone, but now it shows "the requested operation failed". It might be some other error, not sure.

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong message. The error message is "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In at least 99% of all cases: Yes.

It might be only a problem if the .NET 1.1 application uses classes or members that are marked as deprecated and removed in a previous framework of the target framework, like .NET 2.0 e.g.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the CLR is backwards compatible. For example the CLR 4.0 is capable of loading assemblies compiled against CLR 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Like say before yes, but maybe you could use the 2.0 instead ?
'cause it solved a lot of security issues and provide better perfs.
I don't see at all where an 2.0 net app will not work (even with mono).

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that the asker is not *creating* an application targeting version 1.1 of the Framework, but instead trying to run an existing app.